# How to set focus to an ion-grid or ion-list in a tabbed ionic application?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How do you set focus to an ion-list in the second tab such that the up/down arrow keys works right after selecting the second tab?
The current behavior is that I have to always click first on the list to enable keyboard arrows to work?

When switching tabs an ion-slides receives focus but ion-list does NOT, why is that? (a result of ionic using slider.js in implementing their ion-slides?)

Using @HostListnener and some css highlighting I managed to hack the "desired" behavior of ion-list not getting focus to respond to up/down arrow keys. Perhaps you have a better approach then @HostListener?

I have similar problem with ion-grid inside an ion-content of another tab not receiving focus or reacting to arrow keys. The ultimate goal is to allow the arrow keys and the Enter key to make a selection using of course the keyboard.

See example [ionic-qdwges.stackblitz.io](http://ionic-qdwges.stackblitz.io)
edit here [stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qdwges](http://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qdwges)

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic set Focus programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974003/ionic-set-focus-programmatically)

Comment: No, I started there, and I decided to post more specifically and provide a code example.
Most of the focus post tend to be around and input field, which I know how to do. Thanks